# How to disable FileChangesMonitor in ASP.NET MVC4 for directory/virtualdirectory/at all?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

In my ASP.NET MVC4 app I have `"~/Uploads"` folder. I allow users to upload files to it, separated folder for each user is created.

When folder, like `"~/Uploads/23452367"` is deleted, **AppDomain is shutting down**. Also, if this folder contains subfolders, while deleting, **"Folder is not empty"** exception is thrown.

It is not acceptable, of cource, because if users constantly upload something (temporary thumbnails for pictures in folders are being created and removed), site will be restarting all the time round the clock. 
I can't write files outside project root directory, because they have to be accessible thru the web.

I even created **Virtual Directory** in IIS for `"~/Uploads"` folder, which was linked to another folder outside WWWRoot, but FileChangesMonitor **monitors it as well**. Looks like impossible task for ASP.NET. Please, say that I'm wrong.

Solution, to put in Application_Start()

```
PropertyInfo p = typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public |  BindingFlags.Static);
object o = p.GetValue(null, null);
FieldInfo f = o.GetType().GetField("_dirMonSubdirs", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
object monitor = f.GetValue(o);
MethodInfo m = monitor.GetType().GetMethod("StopMonitoring", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
m.Invoke(monitor, new object[] { });
```

Didn't work.

Editing registry

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET\FCNMode
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET\FCNMode
```

didn't work.

Maybe it's because this solutions are 5-6 years old.

Anyway, I can imagine only one solution by now - to get uploaded files completely out of the ASP.NET MVC app and to set up separate webserver, separate subdomain to serve this just-picture-requests and maybe other static content. This is a good solution for very big projects only.

What if I'm not THAT big?
All opinions are appreciated.

Comment: Just move uploads outside your webroot folder. You only have to assign write/read permissions to the identity running the apppool.

Comment: How will it be accessible via web request in this case?

Comment: Have a controller for route ~\Uploads\{userid}\* that handles incoming calls and then serves files back by reading from your actual uploads folder?

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I didn't think about that. Thank you. One moment, though, wouldn't it be a bit slow? IIS would handle that request faster, I think

Comment: In your question you stated `You was not THAT big`

Comment: Well, yes, your answer is absolutely correct.